# How to capture insert exception in db2 for Unique constraint in a node.js application?

Tags: node.js, insert, db2, ibm-cloud, unique-constraint

I am new to node.js and I have a node.js app on IBM DB2 Bluemix connecting to a DB2 database. I am trying to insert a record in the database, but I want to know if the insert operation fails due to unique-constraint, then how can I capture the exception and pass the error message to the calling function.
Here is the code where I am calling the createItem:-

```
dao.createItem(conn,ItemData,function(err, isValid){
if (isValid != '1') {
console.log(err);
console.log("Operation failed");
res.status(603);
var errmsg = "Operation failed due to duplicate values";
var errJson =util.buildErrorJson(601,err,errmsg);
console.log(err.stack);
res.send(errJson);
}
```

Below is the createItem:-

```
exports.createItem = function(conn,ItemData, callback) {
conn.beginTransaction(function (err) {
if (err) {
//could not begin a transaction for some reason. 
console.log(err);
return conn.closeSync();
}
var stmt = "SELECT count(*) as rows_inserted from final table (INSERT INTO   T1(col1, col2, col3) values ('p1', 'p2', 'p3'))"
conn.query(stmt,function (err, rows) {
if (err) {
console.log(err);
} else {
console.log(rows);
var dataarr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
var rows_inserted = dataarr[0].ROWS_INSERTED;
console.log("rows inserted" + rows_inserted); 
conn.commitTransaction(function (err){
if (err) {
console.log(err);
callback(err,rows);
}
});
}
});
```

The problem is that when the insert operation fails at conn.query, I am not sure how to capture the error details and pass on the same to the calling method. 
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When the insert operation fails at conn.query, the result callback includes the error message as the first parameter. You can simply execute the top-level callback with that error object, in the same way you do this in commitTransaction.

```
exports.createItem = function(conn,ItemData, callback) {
conn.beginTransaction(function (err) {
if (err) {
//could not begin a transaction for some reason. 
console.log(err);
return conn.closeSync();
}
var stmt = "SELECT count(*) as rows_inserted from final table (INSERT INTO   T1(col1, col2, col3) values ('p1', 'p2', 'p3'))"
conn.query(stmt,function (err, rows) {
if (err) {
console.log(err);
callback(err);
} else {
console.log(rows);
var dataarr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
var rows_inserted = dataarr[0].ROWS_INSERTED;
console.log("rows inserted" + rows_inserted); 
conn.commitTransaction(function (err){
if (err) {
console.log(err);
callback(err,rows);
}
});
}
});
```